# What is Azure’s equivalents to AWS Cognito Identity Pool?

Tags: amazon-cognito, azure-ad-b2c

I think Azure AD is the equivalent to AWS Cognito User Pool, but is there an equivalent to AWS Cognito Identity Pool?

Answer (score 0):

"Amazon Cognito identity pools support both authenticated and unauthenticated identities. Authenticated identities belong to users who are authenticated by any supported identity provider. Unauthenticated identities typically belong to guest users".

Azure AD and Azure AD B2C can federate with any Identity provider that supports OpenID Connect or SAML 2. Azure AD also supports federation via WS-Fed.

Azure AD supports guest users - typically known as external identies.

Comment: AWS identity pool issues key pairs, not access tokens. I think Azure AD issues access tokens,